# Base64 images not displaying on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, image, base64, mern

Holla, fellow developers!

I made this e-commerce app using the MERN stack, where I create a product as an admin, upload an image, save it in the database as binary data and then display it on the SHOP page using the following code:

```js
src={`data:image/jpg;base64,${img.data}`}
```

And although this works perfectly in my PC browser and all images are displayed accordingly, when I open the app on my mobile device some of the images are displayed and some are not, which makes no sense, since they are all JPEG, they are all roughly the same size.

Is there some kind of a rule when using base64 encoded images on mobile devices or do they not work all together and if there's a way to fix it, how can I do it?

Also what are the best and most reliable practices when it comes to saving images in the database and displaying them when working with the MERN stack?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Technically this should not be the case. I have something similar and it is working perfectly fine. 
I am uploading an image
converting to base64 & 
made an api call to upload the same.
Made one more api call to fetch the same and using it with image src.
So here is my base 64 conversion.

//base 64 conversion//

```
`onChange=event=>{
        this.setState({
            file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
        })
        const ProjectfileSize = Math.round((event.target.files[0].size / 1024)); 
        this.setState({
            fileSize: ProjectfileSize
        })
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        reader.onload = () => 
{
            const base64File = reader.result.replace(/^data:[a-z]+\/[a-z\-]+;base64,/, "");
            this.setState({
                convertedFile: base64File
            })
        };
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        };

}
`
```